# Building chromium project for Android

Tags: android, chromium

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions) to build chromium project for android on ubuntu 14.04. I was able to successfully check out the code, now I'm trying to configure the build. I'm using GN to configure, so I run "gn args out/Default", however I get this error: gn.py: Could not find gn executable at: /home/moon/chromium/src/buildtools/linux64/gn

All I have in that above folder is sha1 files, I don't seem to have python files. However, I had not received any errors during checkout process. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you but I managed to build Chromium finally.

Most probably, you **may not successfully** install any necessary dependencies.

Since you are on Linux, run the following command under `src`:

```
$ ./build/install-build-deps.sh
```

After this you can rerun the command:

```
$ gn gen out/Default
```

Comment: I ran the two commands without any interrupt, yet your solution doesn't seem to be working, at least for me, and the error message still persists !!

Answer (score 2):

After giving credit to [Brett Wilson](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/ybtMSTN4yHg), run:

```
gclient runhooks
```

It worked for me.